# delete data using ajax and codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have problem in deleting data using ajax I tried first to test if I click the button to make alert action so it not work.
**this is my controller code**

```
public function indexajax()
  {

      $this->load->model("usersmodel");
      $data["allu"]=$this->usersmodel->ShowAllUsers("users");
      $data['pagetitle']=" -->All Users Using Ajax<--";
      $this->load->view("template/admin/header",$data);
      $this->load->view("users/allusersusingajax");
      $this->load->view("template/admin/footer");
  }

  public function get_all_users()
  {
     if($this->input->post("action")=='FetchAllUserUingAjax1'){

        $this->load->model("usersmodel");
         $x=  $data["allu"]=$this->usersmodel->ShowAllUsers("users");
         foreach ($x as $a):
             echo'<tr>
        <td>'.$a->id.'</td>
        <td>'.$a->username.'</td>
        <td><button class="deletenew" id="'.$a->id.'">delete</button></td>

        </tr>';
         endforeach;
      }

public function deleteusers()
{
    $id=$this->input->post("id");
    $this->load->model("usersmodel");
    $this->usersmodel->deleteusers($id);
}
```

**this is my model code for deleting**

```
public function deleteusers($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    if($this->db->delete("users")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**/**************this is view page *****/**

```
<div class="userdataajax table-responsive">
    <table class=" table table-responsive table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>image</th>
            <th> full name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>usertype</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>reg date</th>
            <th>reg time</th>
            <th>delete</th>
            <th>edit</th>
            <th>Activate</th>
            <th>disactivate</th>

        </tr>

    </table>
</div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        FetchAllUserUingAjax();

        function FetchAllUserUingAjax() {

            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo base_url()?>Users/get_all_users',
                method:"post",

                success:function (data) {
                    $(".userdataajax table").append(data);
                }
            })

            var action="FetchAllUserUingAjax1";
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url()?>Users/get_all_users",
                method:"post",
                data:{action:action},
                success:function (data) {
                    $(".userdataajax table tr").not("table  
                   tr:first").remove();

                    $(".userdataajax table").append(data);
                    Table();
                }
            })
        };
        $(".deletenew").on("click",function () {
           alert("engex");//this alert not working

            var id=$(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({

                url:"<?php echo base_url()?>Users/deleteusers",
                method:"post",
                data:{id:id},
                success:function () {
                    alert("deleted");
                    FetchAllUserUingAjax();
                }
            })
        })
    })

</script>
```

**// but if I remove foreach *(foreach)* from controller and put it in view page, delete is working. I want to know what is my problem.**

Comment: You haven't actually said what problem you're facing. An error?

Comment: no delete happen

Comment: Help us to help you. We shouldn't have to extract bits of information. Have you checked for a MySQL error? Have you checked the compiled SQL query that attempts the delete? And what happens if you run that manually in the DB? Do some debugging.

Comment: my querey  have no fault  @Utkanos  if you delete foreach that found in controller in get_all_users in functon  and put it in view  you will found this  code  workind without any problem

Comment: Here is a pausable explanation as to why it is not working. Everything is fine with the code except the way you are trying to call. You see when you include it in the view (foreach view), button is rendered along the view but if you use it from the controller, it is actually done after loading the view. So in that case you will need to use jquery on function. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: when i clicked the button for delete  no ajaxa request  found

Comment: Look at the link which i included, specifically the second example. Ajax cant call if it doesn't know that there is a delete button on the page.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you set the click handler for the delete buttons, these buttons do not exist in the page (yet...) as they are being loaded with another ajax request.

To bind the buttons that are later added to the page, you can use event delegation. To do that, you need to change your click handler from this:

```
$(".deletenew").on("click",function () {
```

to:

```
$('body').on('click', '.deletenew', function () {
```

I have delegated it to the `body` element, but you can use any element that will contain the buttons and is already available on page load / DOM ready.

Answer (score 1):

## controller code

I think your alert is not showing because your table is showing by ajax In this code you have to use deletenew function, when click on delete button.

```
public function get_all_users()
      {
         if($this->input->post("action")=='FetchAllUserUingAjax1'){

            $this->load->model("usersmodel");
             $x=  $data["allu"]=$this->usersmodel->ShowAllUsers("users");
             foreach ($x as $a):
                 echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$a->id.'</td>
            <td>'.$a->username.'</td>
            <td><button class="deletenew" id="'.$a->id.'" onclick="deletenew(this.id);">delete</button></td>

            </tr>';
             endforeach;
          }
```

## view page delete function

This is deletenew function this will work when you click on delete button

```
    function deletenew(id){
     alert("engex");

      $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo base_url()?>Users/deleteusers",
          method:"post",
          data:{id:id},
          success:function () {
              alert("deleted");
              FetchAllUserUingAjax();

          }

      })
  }
```

I hope this code will work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
       //change Controller function 

     public function get_all_users()

     {

        if($this->input->post("action")=='FetchAllUserUingAjax1')
    {

         $this->load->model("usersmodel");
        // print_r($this->input->post("action"));
         echo ($this->input->post("action"));
        $data["allu"]=$this->usersmodel->ShowAllUsers("users");
        $this->load->view("template/admin/header");
       //make another view show_users,make a button in page
       //alluersusing ajax give that button id 'but'
        $this->load->view("users/show_users,$data");

        $this->load->view("template/admin/footer");

     }


 //copy paste the code below in  show_users view


        foreach ($x as $a):

                         echo'<tr>

                    <td>'.$a->id.'</td>

                    <td>'.$a->username.'</td>

        <td><button class="btn btn primary" onclick=del(<?php echo '.$a->id.' ?>)>delete</button></td>

                    </tr>';
                     endforeach;


//Ajax Delete function

<script>

 function del(id) {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo base_url('Users/deleteusers')?>' +"/"+ id,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#get").html(data);


            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I have passed the id in the javaScript function you can see in foreach loop this is the core change I have done.